# Nothing I try can override this CSS selector

Tags: css

The one I want to be applied

```
input[type=text]#lookupFilterName.hlLightRed {
  background-color: lightpink !important;
}
```

The one that actually shows up, in all browsers no matter what I do.

```
input[type=text], textarea, input[type=password] {
  background: #ffffff;
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJod…EiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #afafaf 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#afafaf));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#afafaf 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#afafaf 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#afafaf 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#afafaf 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#afafaf',GradientType=0 );
}
```

The only way I can get this particular textbox to be pink, is to open up developer tools and turn off all the backgrounds in the (input[type=text], textarea, input[type=password]) one.

Both are coming from 2 different style sheets.
Target element is:

```
<input id="lookupFilterName" type=text class="fullcellwdith changesdontmatter hlLightRed"  />
```

Why is this crazy thing happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simply because you should write background instead of background-color. The linear gradiant on the "background" element have priority over "background-color"

Just do this:

```
    input[type=text]#lookupFilterName.hlLightRed {
      background: lightpink;
    }
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q1fxjg59/1/

Comment: Cool. First thought in my mind but, didn't know linear gradiant has more priority than `background-color` with `important!`

Comment: Thank you. Was losing sanity.